# In how many ways can you choose $k$ out of $n$ people standing in line, So there's a space of at least 3 people between them

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can you choose $k$ out of $n$ people standing in line, So there's a space of at least $3$ people between them.

Actually, I don't even know how to start on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: You can think of this as a [stars-and-bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28probability%29) problem. The $k$ people chosen are the bars, the $n-k$ other people are the stars, and you have to distribute the stars so that there are at least $3$ between each pair of adjacent bars. Your problem is to count the ways to do this.

Equivalently, let $x_0$ be the number of people to the left of the first person chosen, $x_i$ the number between the $i$-th and $(i+1)$-st people chosen (reading from left to right) for $i=1,\dots,k-1$, and $x_k$ the number to the right of the $k$-th person chosen. Then you want the number of solutions to

$$x_0+x_1+\ldots+x_k=n-k$$

in non-negative integers such that $x_i\ge 3$ for $i=1,\dots,k-1$.

You’ve probably seen other stars-and-bars problems by now, but even if you haven’t, the linked article gives a reasonably good explanation.

Comment: I think you mean $i = 1, ..., k-1$.

Comment: @Narut: I do indeed; thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x_i$ denote the distance between the men with numbers i and i+1. Then $x_i\ge 3$ and

$$
  x_1+x_2+\ldots x_{k-1} \le n
$$

Put $y_i = x_i-2$. Then $y_i\ge 1$ and

$$
  y_1+y_2+\ldots y_{k-1} \le n - 2(k-1)
$$

The last inequality is the problem of choosing $k$ out of $n-2(k-1)$ people whiout any restrictions. So the answer is $C_{n-2(k-1)}^k = \binom{n-2(k-1)}{k}$